# Calculating a parameter for which three complex vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

Given are the vectors $$(1, 2 + i, 0), (1-i, 2, 2), (a, 2i + 5, 1) \in \mathbb{C}$$

I`m suppossed to figure out for which values of $a\in \mathbb{C}$ are these vectors linearly independent.

I tried figuring out the solution by solving the linear system of equations, but quickly figured out that this isn't getting me anywhere.

By trying out some values I figured out that for $\lambda_1 = -2, \lambda_2 = -\frac{1}{2}, \lambda_3 = 1$ the vectores are linearly dependent for $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(5-i)$. This isn't a good approach to this problem though, and I'm kind of stuck here and don't know how to analytically find values for $a$. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Form a $3\times 3$ matrix with those points and compute the determinant. You can use linearity of the determinant (in terms of rows & columns) to simplify your life.

Comment: @copper.hat We haven't learned about determinants yet and are strictly told to only apply out current knowledge to the problems given. There must be a different way to solve this problem.

Comment: Find the values of $a$ for which you can write the last vector in terms of the other two, then the answer is all the other values  of $a$. Note, there is exactly one value of $a$ for which they are dependent.

Comment: Well, as said in the post I already figured out that the vectors are linearly dependent for $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(5-i)$, but I`m fairly sure that this isn't the only solution for which they are linearly dependent..

Comment: Well, I am fairly sure that it is, and the only 'bad' value is $a=1.7+i2.1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "bad" value and how did you calculate it?

Comment: The above value that I computed is incorrect, I forgot Octave takes the conjugate transpose!

Comment: Ah alright, that valued confused me more than anything. Now the problem makes sense to me, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let us write the vectors as

$$U_1=(1,2,0)+i(0,1,0)$$

$$U_2=(1,2,2)+i(-1,0,0)$$

$$U_3=(a_1,5,1)+i(a_2,2,0)$$

from here we see that it should be

$$U_3-2U_1=\lambda U_2$$

$$\implies \lambda =\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies a_1-2=\frac{1}{2}, a_2=-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies a=\frac{1}{2}(5-i)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the first two vectors are linearly independent, we need only find
the values of $a$ for which the the last vector lies in the span of the first two.

Let the three vectors be $v_1,v_2,v_3$ and suppose
$v_3 = x v_1 + y v_2$. If you look at the last two components, then there
are unique $x,y$ such that the bottom two components match. Then
if the three vectors are dependent, we must have $a = x [v_1]_1 + y [v_2]_1$.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I got the same solutiion by trial-and-error, but this is actually a general way to approach a problem like this. Thank you!